# Delegate creator to create comparitor for nullable types

Tags: c#, delegates, nullable

I'm using a custom `ListView` control that cannot handle null values with its internal comparing methods. My dream would be for comparison to just work, without much configuration.

Most of the columns have values of nullable decimal type, but some have other types, like nullable integers or non-nullable types.

Currently for every colum I have to write:

```
_priceColumn.Comparitor = delegate (object x, object y)
{
    Ticker xTicker = (Ticker)x;
    Ticker yTicker = (Ticker)y;

    return Nullable.Compare<Decimal>(xTicker.Price, yTicker.Price);
};
```

I would like to be able to write something like:

```
_priceColumn.Comparitor = ColumnHelpers.CreateNullableComparitor(Ticker.Price) //It would have to look up the type of Ticker.Price itself and call the correct Nullable.Compare.
```

or

```
_priceColumn.Comparitor = ColumnHelpers.CreateNullableComparitor(Ticker.Price, Decimal?) //I pass  Decimal? to it, which is the type of Ticker.Price
```

I don't know how to make it create something that matches the signature of the required delegate.

Its probably easy to solve with some generic magic or by checking the type and choosing the correct method.

The custom `ListView` that I'm using is this one:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20052/Outlook-Style-Grouped-List-Control

Comment: If the type of value is not nullable, do you still want to use the `Nullable.Compare` method?

Comment: What is the type of `_priceColumn.Comparitor`? `Comparison<object>`?

Comment: Yes you are right, it is `Comparison<object>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want your method to return a `Comparison<object>`. You can write such a method:

```
public static Comparison<object> CreateNullableComparitor<T>(Func<Ticker, T?> keySelector) where T: struct {
    return (o1, o2) => Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(keySelector((Ticker)o1), keySelector((Ticker)o2));
}
```

And use it like so:

```
CreateNullableComparitor(x => x.Price);
```

If the value's type is non-nullable, type inference does not work here, so you'll have to do:

```
CreateNullableComparitor<decimal>(x => x.NonNullablePrice);
```

Comment: One single method can easily handle reference types, nullable value types and non-nullable value types all in one: `return (o1, o2) => Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(keySelector((Ticker)o1), keySelector((Ticker)o2));`

Comment: @hvd Thanks for reminding me! I totally forgot about `Comparer.Default`!

Comment: I don't really understand even the syntax of the solution. But thats good, I guess I will read more about Lamba Expressions and generics.

Comment: @Sweeper When I tried to compile your code I get this error: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'int' because it is not a delegate type` What am I missing?

Comment: Which line did you get that? @maer show me the whole line.

Comment: .Its is this line: `return (o1, o2) => Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(keySelector((Ticker)o1), keySelector((Ticker)o2));`

Comment: @maer See the edit. And if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: @sweeper sure, I was going to mark it already but then I thought I should first test the code. There are still errors in this line: `return (o1, o2) => Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(keySelector((Ticker)o1), keySelector((Ticker)o2));` The Error is:  `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T?' to 'T'` and `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'T?' to 'T'` ... Do you know what to do? Thank for helping again!

Comment: @sweeper Now I **changed** it again to the following and it works only for nullable types (added the "?" to the Comparer<T?>) `return (o1, o2) => Comparer<T?>.Default.Compare(keySelector((Ticker)o1), keySelector((Ticker)o2));`

Comment: Now it doesn't work however on none-nullable Type like decimal. This is how I use it "rank" is decimal in the following code: `ColumnHelpers.CreateNullableComparitor(x => x.Rank);` Errormessage: `The type arguments for method 'ColumnsHelpers.CreateNullableComparitor<T>(Func<Ticker, T?>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.` The solution is probably obivious ... how do I "specify the type argument explicitly"? Sorry for bothering, I hope it will be over soon!

Comment: @maer you specify type arguments by writing `<decimal>` after the method name, just like my last snippet

Comment: Oh ok great, thanks a lot! And if somebody has idea about the other stackexchange question I posted I'd appreciate any pointers there, too.  I'm not quite sure what to do if nobody answers a questions ...